# @media print display:none isn't working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, hide

I have tried for over 3 weeks now with different implementations trying to get the right section to not display, and have the left section display at full width.  Given that my research shows there is no easy or streamlined way to quickly render Print views without reviewing the print preview, I am asking for some help to figure this out.

the print media css that is not working is this:

```
#gc {
    width: 100%;
}
#asideTrack {
/*      width: 100%;*/
    display: none;
}
.asideTrack {
/*      width: 100%;*/
    display: none;
}
.slideAside {
/*      width: 100%;*/
    display: none;
}
#slideAside {
    display:none
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The aside block is not displayed in print preview (tested on Firefox and IE), so the problem appears to be something else than what the heading and the description say. Before clarifying the problem description, please check out the syntactic errors. The W3C markup validator reports 53 errors, and the W3C CSS Validator reports 43 errors (when CSS3 is specified and vendor extensions are treated as warnings only).

Comment: yes, they are not visible, but the display on the print preview is not the same as if you were to manually hide the aSide.   The left side's width does not 'adjust' to a full width.  The section is still present, just not visible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

***In CSS lower rule overwrites the top if they have the same priority (depending on selector)***

You write your common css not in @media block, and it is lower then your @media print block, so it overwrites your @media print styles. For example, it is cause why in print preview your left block has width 74% (because this rule is lower then rule of @media print block where you say it is 100%).

*I hope it is helpful.*

***Solutions***

1. In your css file you may place media print block to the end of file.
2. Add `!important` directives to some rules in media print block. ie:
    p {
        color: red !important;
    }
3. Place your special css for screen in media screen block.

Comment: So how do I overrite the lower rule with the @media block?

Comment: the !important worked.  THank you.  did not know about the ordering.   yet again, a reason I still need [this][1]
[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11161631/the-hunt-for-a-css-attribute-editable-interactive-user-interface-learning-tool